# Tower of Hanoi (with Class) index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing, towers-of-hanoi

i'm doing an exercise about the famous game "Tower of Hanoi" and i have an error when i run my code. But i don't know how to fix it. Here's my code:

```
class HanoiT():

    def __init__(self, content=None):
        if content is None:
            self.content=[]
        else:
            self.content=content

    def addmethod(self, new_disk): #Add an element on the beginning of the list
        if new_disk <= self.content[0]:
            self.content.insert(0, new_disk)
        else:
            raise ValueError("No disk may be placed on top of a smaller disk")


    def deletemethod(self): #Delete the first element of a list
        self.content.pop(0)

    def affichage(self): #Method to print the list which represent the "disk" putted on the tower from the top to bottom
        for i in self.content:
            print(i, end=" ")

    def movedisk(self, Tsource, Ttarget): 
        Ttarget.addmethod(Tsource.content[0])
        Tsource.deletemethod()

    def movetower(self, N, Tour1, Tour3, Tour2):
        if N >= 1:
            self.movetower(N-1, Tour1, Tour2, Tour3)
            self.movedisk(Tour1, Tour3)
            self.movetower(N-1, Tour2, Tour3, Tour1)




N = 4
Tour1 = HanoiT([x for x in range(1, N+1)])
Tour1.affichage()
Tour2 = HanoiT([])
Tour3 = HanoiT([])
h = HanoiT()
h.movetower(N, Tour1, Tour2, Tour3)
```

So, when i run it raise an IndexError: list index out of range, in line 17, which is " if new_disk <= self.content[0]:" in the add_method

I saw that an Indexerror can be raised if the value aren't in the list or out of the range, but i don't know what's the problem in my case.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say that the integer in the list represent the disk on the tower and with respect to the rules of this games: "No disk may be placed on top of a smaller disk."

Comment: Try printing the content

Answer (score 0):

`h` is created without a content:

```
h = HanoiT()
```

which means that its content will be an empty list (see `__init__`).

and a line later, when you call it with:

```
h.movetower(N, Tour1, Tour2, Tour3)
```

it will recursively call the class functions until it will reach the line where you try to pull `self.content[0]` only that since `content` is empty - there is no such index available to access in `content`

Comment: Oh yes, now i understand the error raisen, but i don't see how to fix it, i have to write an iterative function instead of the recursive one?

Comment: It would be easier to write a recursive function, yes. I can give you an answer that includes the full implementation but you won't learn much out of it (further, you can probably google it....). In order to learn you have to go back to the drawing board and try to figure out what's wrong in the current design and how should you change it.

Comment: I wrote an iterative solution for the movetower but it still raise en Index Error, i find in wikipédia the algorithm of the iterative solutions and i did this :    

 def movetower(self,N,Tour1,Tour2,Tour3):
        moves= 2**N-1
        for i in range(1,moves+1):
            if i%3==1:
                self.movedisk(Tour1,Tour3)
            if i%3==2:
                self.movedisk(Tour1,Tour2)
            if i%3==0:
                self.movedisk(Tour3,Tour2)